# Powershell does not seem to cope with a big number of parameter sets in a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Is there any restriction to the number of parameter sets a cmdlet can have? I've made a cmdlet which has 56 switch parameters and I want each one to be mandatory in its own parameter set. For some reason powershell groups the (n+1)th with the 1st, the (n+2)th with the 2nd etc, ending up with no more than n parameter sets; if I counted correctly n was 32.
This is what my cmdlet looks like:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Foo")]
public class GetFoo : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public string ParamA {get;set;}

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    public string ParamB {get;set;}

    [Parameter]
    public string ParamC {get;set;}

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Group1", Mandatory = true)]
    public SwitchParameter Param1 {get;set;}

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Group2", Mandatory = true)]
    public SwitchParameter Param2 {get;set;}
    . . .

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Group56", Mandatory = true)]
    public SwitchParameter Param56 {get;set;}
}
```

Expected:

```
PS> Get-Help Get-Foo
  Get-Foo -Param1 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
  Get-Foo -Param2 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
  . . .
  Get-Foo -Param56 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
```

Actual:

```
PS> Get-Help Get-Foo
  Get-Foo -Param1 -Param33 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
  Get-Foo -Param2 -Param34 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
  . . .
  Get-Foo -Param24 -Param56 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
  Get-Foo -Param25 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
  . . .
  Get-Foo -Param32 [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
```

I'm breaking my head and can't see what's wrong with the way I've constructeed the cmdlet; I don't see this behaviour if I decrease the number of parametersets. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a limitation of Get-Help?  Could you create a C# class   
    ParameterGrouping 
    public SwitchParameter Param1 {get;set;}
... Param 9

Then in your Cmdlet use a few ParameterGrouping parameters to get past the limitation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not just a Get-Help issue, even when I try to use the cmdlet, e.g. Get-Foo -Param24, it's complaining -Param56 is not set. ParameterGrouping is an interesting suggestion but it doesn't work particularly well if the parameters have no logic connection with each other - perhaps it would be more appropriate to break it down to different cmdlets...

Comment: The same limitation is present for script-based advanced functions with cmdlet binding as well. It seems there is a limit defined some where in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a limit of 32 ParameterSets per cmdlet.  See if you can test it out by creating 65 parameter sets and see if -Param65 is in set 1 (with -Param1 and -Param33).

A workaround would be to change your SwitchParameters into a Parameter that takes an Enum containing all of your switch values.

```
Get-Foo -ParamD <EnumParams1To56> [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB <string>] [-ParamC <string>]
```